# Instagram links open in-app browser instead of external/native browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, instagram, instagram-api

If I have a link in my profile, the link opens up an in-app browser either from iOS or Android. Is it possible to open up an external browser instead? Possibly in my own site, if I can detect if user uses mobile, open native browser? Perhaps this is a solution with javascript?

The issue is because users who are logged into my site, and then click on the link within Instagram the in-app browser doesn't keep the user logged in.

Answer (score 7):

That’s possible and simple!
you must cheat the Instagram’s in-app browser. The weakness point of Instagram’s in-app browser is file downloading. When you ask it to download a file, it invokes an external browser and this is our golden key.

You first need to check which browser has your customer come to your website with.
In other words:

```
<script>
   if(navigator.userAgent.includes("Instagram")){
       window.location.href = "https://mywebsite.com/DummyBytes";
   }
</script>
```

Then, implement the DummyBytes API. This API returns a different response based on the viewer’s browser. If the viewer’s browser is Instagram’s in-app browser, it will return some dummy bytes as a file, otherwise it will return a response that redirects the viewer’s browser to your main website (mywebsite.com)

```
<?php
    $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strpos($userAgent, 'Instagram')) {
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= blablabla');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        @readfile($file);
    }
    else{
        header('Location: https://halterapp.com');
    }
?>
```

If you want more guidance, see link below:
[Opening of your website in the viewer’s external browser automatically instead of Instagram’s in-app browser](https://medium.com/@sasan.salem/opening-of-your-website-in-the-viewers-external-browser-automatically-instead-of-instagram-s-8aca5ee7e22f)

Comment: @J0ker98 unfortunately it doesn't work on the IOS. I tried to find a way but due to the IOS's limitations, the browser does not recognize the "file" concept and shows the bytes of the file in the browser. All you can do is detect the client's OS and if it was IOS, ask your client to use an external browser

Comment: is there a solution or an alternative for iOS?

Comment: @Mario Unfortunately it doesn’t work on the IOS. it works only on android devices.

Comment: I did some testing on iOS and found that the iOS WebView has a built-in file renderer.
For this reason on iOS the external browser does not open.
Maybe sending some specific file type or some specific mime-type that is not supported by the file renderer will open the external browser.