# Open link in system browser instead of in app browser

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Link opened via instagram or facebook opens in their in-app browser but some of the feature of my website not work in-app browser. How i can open this in mobile system browser.

I tried doing below but doesn't work.

```js
window.open("https://google.com", "_system")
```

Please help. I want something like below
[image]

Comment: try changing default browser to browser you like in phone settings and try

Comment: @Phil I tried but instagram still opens in in-app browser only.

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217071/instagram-links-open-in-app-browser-instead-of-external-native-browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217071/instagram-links-open-in-app-browser-instead-of-external-native-browser

Answer (score 4):

In-app browsers also break a site of mine.

I'm still hoping for better more thoughtful work on Androids and iOS device developers for web devs when it comes to in-app browsers.

It's a huge issue that there isn't a more elegant solution for detecting in-app (on iOS and Android) and redirecting to default browser (on iOS).

My 'ok' solution for Android

- Detect if android with something like Bowser https://github.com/bowser-js/bowser
- Detect if in-app with https://github.com/shalanah/inapp-spy
- Try auto-redirecting on detected android in-app browsers (don't do on all browsers or you'll get an infinite loop). Intent link on android will open in their default browser.

```
window.location = "intent:https://example.com#Intent;end";
```

- For the in-app browsers that don't allow for redirecting - which is a lot of them - serve up a button to open in their default browser

```
<a 
  href="intent:https://example.com#Intent;end" 
  target="_blank">
  Open Browser
</a>
```

My only solution for iOS is serving up a site with directions to open in a new browser if I detect that is in-app via the repo above.

UPDATE:
I use `inapp-spy` now - a fork and refactor I made from `detect-inapp` -  since `detect-inapp` is no longer maintained.

Comment: you are an angel!